# Live-server error in VSCode: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, liveserver

I am learning JavaScript for the second time, first time I did not have this problem. I have Nodejs installed and start live-server from the terminal. Whenever I save and the page reloads, the console gives me this error message:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsncA.png)

It usually happens when more than 10-15 seconds have passed since the last reload. If I reload immediately, it's gone. Live-server works perfectly even when I get the error message, so I can technically still work with it but this error message is highly annoying as it gives me the feeling with every reload that there's a problem with my code.

I've been trying to google for a solution for days now and I can't find anything specific, only that this error usually comes up for people building a Chrome extension. I tried changing the address of the live-server, updated Chrome, VSCode and Node, deleted all unnecessary Chrome extensions but nothing seems to work. I tried with Safari, as far as I went, it did not produce the same error (but I still prefer to use Chrome for LS). Thank you!

Comment: Which command are you using? add the code you tried

Comment: You mean in the terminal? I just open terminal and write live-server and it starts. Changing the address I did with live-server --address=something but since I have no idea what addresses it can use I was not able to change it, only the port but it also didn't work. Otherwise I have not tried anything in the terminal.

Comment: you can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) instead of live-server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.